# Filing in gap in stacked area chart

Tags: javascript, dimple.js

I have a stacked area chart with two series of current and projected values. Each has values which are adjusted interactively, and are assigned colors (the projected areas will be a shade of the current areas). I can't work out how to not have a break between the 'current' and 'projected' series. If I join them (simulated by clicking the shapes in the jsfiddle) all the values are stacked for that year. I could work out subtracted values, but that seems hacky. Is there a better way to do this? I should note this is a slice of a larger design which I'm hoping to not substantially revamp.

http://jsfiddle.net/d3jo0uu5/4/

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
var s1 = [
    {series: 'S1', x: '2014', y: 10},
    {series: 'S1', x: '2015', y: 15},
    {series: 'S1', x: '2016', y: 15},

    {series: 'S2', x: '2014', y: 20},
    {series: 'S2', x: '2015', y: 25},
    {series: 'S2', x: '2016', y: 30},

    {series: 'P1', x: '2017', y: 10},
    {series: 'P1', x: '2018', y: 15},
    {series: 'P1', x: '2019', y: 15},

    {series: 'P2', x: '2017', y: 20},
    {series: 'P2', x: '2018', y: 25},
    {series: 'P2', x: '2019', y: 30}
];

var chart = new dimple.chart(svg);
var x = chart.addTimeAxis("x", ['x'], '%Y', '%Y');
x.timePeriod = d3.time.years;
x.timeInterval = 1;

var y = chart.addCategoryAxis("y", "y");

var s = chart.addSeries(['series'], dimple.plot.area);
s.stacked = true;
s.data = s1;
chart.assignClass('P1', 'future');
chart.assignClass('P2', 'future');

chart.draw();

s.shapes.on("click", function (e) {
    s1.push({series: 'P1', x: '2016', y: 15});
    s1.push({series: 'P2', x: '2016', y: 20});
    chart.draw(1000);
});
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could figure out how to get what I believe you want is to divide the data set in half (and add two series) and then add in duplicate values for 2017 for the first two data groups :

```
var s1data = [
  {series: 'S1', x: '2014', y: 10},
  {series: 'S1', x: '2015', y: 15},
  {series: 'S1', x: '2016', y: 15},
      {series: 'S1', x: '2017', y: 15}, //added

  {series: 'S2', x: '2014', y: 20},
  {series: 'S2', x: '2015', y: 25},
  {series: 'S2', x: '2016', y: 30},
      {series: 'S2', x: '2017', y: 30} //added
];

var s2data = [
      ...P1 values...
];

...same...

var s = chart.addSeries(['series'], dimple.plot.area);
s.stacked = false;
s.data = s1data;

var s2 = chart.addSeries(['series'], dimple.plot.area);
s2.stacked = false;
s2.data = s2data;
```

That give you this output :

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/d3jo0uu5/5/

Comment: thanks for your response. I've tried the approach of adding a series yet had the same result. will experiment further.

Comment: Got it working! thanks for getting me to return to that approach.